# How to change height of visible area in umano sliding panel?

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I want to change the height of the panel which is visible by default.

I tried changing umanoPanelHeight but it has absolutely no effect.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.my.app"
                android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
                sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
                sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
                sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
                sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

    <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    // Details omitted  
    />

    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    // Details omitted  
    />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

I came across this problem earlier as well but couldn't solve it then. It looks a very basic thing but I can't figure out. Can someone help me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample with a basic integration and it works perfect. I hope it helps you that you can spot what you are doing different.

I would also change the inner layouts to the simple textviews to see if the problem is there.

**Integration**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //...
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
```

**App manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Style**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="368dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="368dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Both layout and layout1 are working fine and I can see the panel increasing size as I used 368dp instead of 68dp that was the default value. Tested on Android 6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the code mate, I can't understand what  am doing wrong, no matter what value I use no change at all :(